# How do I pull customer, order, product, etc. data from Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, data

I'm trying to set up a simple script to pull customer, order, product, etc. data information from Magento 2.

I have an old script for Magento 1 that does this easily, and quite nicely, but with the total revamp of Magento 2 I'm lost in the weeds again.

I need an example of how to pull an order's information, say between two dates, and echo it for the customer.
Like between 2016-05-01, and 2016-05-10.

I'm planning on putting this script in a sub-folder called /custom-exports/

The simple output I'm looking for should be something like this:

> Date: 2016-05-03 17:12:22
>   Order: 1
>   First Name: Jesse
>   Last Name: Gangi
>   Address 1: 101 Main St
>   Address 2:
>   City: Duluth
>   State: Minnesota
>   Zip: 55816
>   Email: jgangi@aerialapps.com

Any, and all help is much appreciated, as I can't really grasp how to get this data in Magento 2 versus Magento 1.

If I can understand this, then I can branch it off for customers, and products.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to instantiate in a script or in your class the 
Magento\Sales\Model\Order and than getCollection on the model and than filter your data the same you did in M1.

The code for that would be

```
use Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory; //OrderFactory because this the magento 2 way of working with models

class OrderCustomApp 
{

    /**
     * @var OrderFactory
     */
    protected $_orderFactory;

    public function __construct(
        OrderFactory $orderFactory
    )
    {

        $this->_orderFactory = $orderFactory;
    }

    public function getOrders()
    {
        $orderCollection = $this->_orderFactory->create()->getCollection();
        /** filter collection code the same as in magento 1 **/
        return $orderCollection;

    }
```

The same you would do with the customer (Magento\Customer\Model\Customer) and product (Magento\Catalog\Model\Product)

Hope this helps!